# Chromium won't launch as Default Application on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gui, chromium, snap, default-browser

chromium is installed as a snap package, I am able to launch it by clicking the icon or running `chromium` from the terminal. But when I set it as default web browser then clicking a link in other application does nothing.

Comment: This is due to the abysmally broken Snap Chromium Canonical introduced. You can open an issue about it on Ubuntu's issue tracker.